# Problema al momento de consultar las últimas inscripciones de cada disciplina registrada

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: esta es la base de datos es de un gimnasio que hace el control de sus inscripciones]

Intenté hacer una consulta que me traiga la ultima inscripción de cada disciplina en la que este inscrito el cliente, por decir si esta inscrito en dos disciplinas tendría que devolverme los dos últimos registros y probé con esta consulta solo me devuelve un solo registro:

```
SELECT Persona.CI,
       Persona.Nombre,
       Persona.ApellidoPaterno,
       Persona.ApellidoMaterno,
       Persona.Foto,
       ConceptoPago.NombreConceptoPago,
       Diciplina.NombreDiciplina,
       Inscripcion.CodInscripcion,
       Convert(Varchar(10),Inscripcion.FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento,
       Persona.HuellaDactilar
FROM Persona
INNER JOIN Cliente ON Cliente.CodCliente=Persona.CI
INNER JOIN Inscripcion ON Inscripcion.CodCliente=Cliente.CodCliente
INNER JOIN ConceptoPago ON ConceptoPago.CodConceptoPago=Inscripcion.CodConceptaPago
INNER JOIN Diciplina ON Diciplina.CodDiciplina=Inscripcion.CodDiciplina
WHERE Inscripcion.CodInscripcion =
    (SELECT max(Inscripcion.CodInscripcion)
     FROM Inscripcion)
  AND Inscripcion.CodCliente='4556667'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La parte fundamental de tu consulta es la de "Obtener la última inscripción por disciplina (y por cliente)". Esto lo puedes resolver fácilmente de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  CodCliente, CodDiciplina, MAX(CodInscripcion) AS CodInscripcion 
        FROM Inscripcion
        GROUP BY CodCliente, CodDiciplina
```

Agregando lo anterior como sub-consulta logramos llegar a lo que buscas

```
SELECT Persona.CI,
       Persona.Nombre,
       Persona.ApellidoPaterno,
       Persona.ApellidoMaterno,
       Persona.Foto,
       ConceptoPago.NombreConceptoPago,
       Diciplina.NombreDiciplina,
       Inscripcion.CodInscripcion,
       Convert(Varchar(10),Inscripcion.FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento,
       Persona.HuellaDactilar
       FROM Persona
       INNER JOIN Cliente ON Cliente.CodCliente=Persona.CI
       INNER JOIN Inscripcion ON Inscripcion.CodCliente=Cliente.CodCliente

       INNER JOIN (  SELECT  CodCliente, CodDiciplina, MAX(CodInscripcion) AS CodInscripcion    
            FROM Inscripcion
            GROUP BY CodCliente, CodDiciplina
        ) ULTIMAINS
        ON ULTIMAINS.CodCliente = InscripcionInscripcion
        AND ULTIMAINS.CodDiciplina = Inscripcion.CodDiciplina
    AND ULTIMAINS.CodInscripcion = Inscripcion.CodInscripcion

       INNER JOIN ConceptoPago ON ConceptoPago.CodConceptoPago=Inscripcion.CodConceptaPago
       INNER JOIN Diciplina ON Diciplina.CodDiciplina=Inscripcion.CodDiciplina
       WHERE Inscripcion.CodCliente='4556667'
```

Comment: lo eh probado lo que si funciona bien es lo que pusiste de subconsulta eso funciona bien por separado pero cuando unimos a lo otro ya no trae las ultimas sino todas de cada disciplina

Comment: ah se donde era el problema  solo faltaba el Inscripcion.CodInscripcion=ULTIMAINS.CodInscripcion muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Cierto @Rodrigo Torrico, corregido